# Trouble visualising mixed-effect models

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, mixed-models

My model fit doesn't seem to match my data. Does this have to do with the log transformation? With the scaling? Or is there another problem?

I'm trying to visualise the effect of distance on PAI and this for the different types in my datatset (T1, T2 and T3). The effect of the other predictors I would like to keep constant (but if this isn't possible they can be involved in the visualisation).

```
m1PAI <- lmer(PAI~ (scale(HMSL)  +Type + scale(log(Distance)))^2 + scale(ST_Trees)+ (1|Region:Transect),na.action = na.omit, data=DF, REML=FALSE)

m1line <- predict(m1PAI, se.fit=TRUE, re.form=NA,  type= "response")$fit

p1PAI <- ggplot()+geom_point(data=DF,aes(x=Distance, y=PAI,color=Type))+geom_smooth(aes(x=DF$PAI,y=m1line))
p1PAI  

> dput(head(DF,20))
structure(list(Region = c("BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", 
"BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", 
"BE", "BE", "BE"), Elevation = c("HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", 
"HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "LO", 
"LO", "LO", "LO", "LO"), Type = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1"), plot = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), Distance = c(1.5, 4.5, 12.5, 35.5, 99.5, 
1.5, 4.5, 12.5, 35.5, 99.5, 1.5, 4.5, 12.5, 35.5, 99.5, 1.5, 
4.5, 12.5, 35.5, 75), PAI = c(3.97, 5.43, 6.08, 6.09, 6.28, 5.47, 
5.04, 6.1, 6.12, 6.05, 4.38, 4.37, 3.98, 4.03, 4.97, 5.25, 4.46, 
5.33, 6.26, 6.74), ST_Trees = c(3.97, 4.36333333333333, 2.819375, 
2.45, 2.54333333333333, 3.49241379310345, 3.16764705882353, 3.0252380952381, 
3.57545454545455, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 2.86071428571429, 2.73, 2.73, 
2.66266666666667, 2.58523178807947, 2.53111111111111, 3.19662790697674, 
3.3348275862069), Transect = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

[p1PAI: visualisation model and data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2n3t.png)

I expected my model predictions to be in line with my data points. It seems like there is something wrong with the scale. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(DF)` or if it's too big the output of `dput(head(DF, 30))`?

Comment: yes the x-scale of your fit and points are not the same .. amongst other problems.There is an example of adding an `lmer` line to `ggplot` about half way down the page here  here:  https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/11/16/plot-fitted-lines/

Comment: there is no HMSL column in your data. + add the `library(lme4)` line in the beginning of your code